# Forging packet on a variable

Tags: python, scapy

I'm willing to forge a packet with scapy through a variable and not through bash.
I've written the following code on PyCharm:

```
from scapy.all import *

a=IP()
```

The problem is that PyCharm doesnt recongnize that IP() function and PyCharm "gray" both of the lines, because he doesnt recognize them.

My question is, is this the correct usage in scapy? is IP() is the name of the function that I have to use?

Thanks for the answers

Comment: Regardless of what coloring your IDE applies to the lines, does the code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import scapy

a = scapy.all.IP()
```

Try not to use `from scapy import *` in case of overwriting the same name variable in your namespace.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response friend. Everywhere i read it is written that when using Scapy V2.x, you have to import using "from scapy.all import *", this won't overwrite the namespace, correct?

Comment: @pugilon It depends on where you call 'from scapy.all import *'. For instance, if you have a self-defined class named IP() and you call 'from scapy.all import *' before it, scapy.IP() will be overwritten in this namespace and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. The solution does not work. I get an AttributeError, "'module' object has no attribute 'IP'. Any idea why it doest work..?